# Different ways of using expr command

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm trying to learn the bash expr command inside and out. What are some of the most basic to the most creative/tricky/unexpected ways to use the expr command? Small, manageable examples are great.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly used `expr` for its regular expression matching.  It is sometimes more descriptive than `sed` or `grep`:

```
if expr "$value" : '.*bar$' >/dev/null; then ...
```

Compared to:

```
if echo "$value" | grep '.*bar$' >/dev/null; then ...
```

Or:

```
name=`expr "$filename" : '.*/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$'`
```

Compared to:

```
name=`echo "$filename" | sed 's!.*/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/'`
```

They are functionally equivalent, but expr was slightly faster.  Especially in the older days when some shells had expr as a builtin (DEC Ultrix, for example).

Also, I program in strict Bourne shell syntax, so I still use `expr` for basic arithmatic, for example:

```
count=0
while [ $count -lt 10 ]; do
    # something
    count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Comment: not even POSIX sh?  ouch.

Comment: check some usage here http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html

Comment: As the question was tagged with `bash`, I would prefer `if [[ "$value" =~ .*bar$ ]]; then` instead your two `if` examples, and with `[[ "$filename" =~ .*/(.*)\.[^.]*$ ]]; name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` the other two examples.